# Choosing a framework for building Windows GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface

New to Windows programming.

Which of the following **C++** API can be used to create this kind of GUI in Windows ( it was created using AutoHotkey )

- Windows API,
- MFC,
- Visual C++
- .NET ?

It has quite native interface, and does not require any dependency (small exe).

Moreover, which is preferred for simple apps?

[image]

Comment: All of the above.  Using Winforms is by far the easiest way.

Comment: Um, Visual C++ is not an API. And .NET is not C++.

Comment: You forgot [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) ;o)

Comment: iirc, using .NET from C++ necessitate C++/CLI (aka managed C++), which slightly differs from C++, and is quite a beast to grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above can produce such a GUI. From your list, .net with WinForms is the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot one. The combination of Microsoft's [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library) and [WTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTL) resemble MFC superficially but are meant to be lighter weight. I believe a smaller application can be made with these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider Qt framework it is easy and rapid?